# Unable to locate element by ID

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've been searching through all the related topics I can find and haven't found an answer that works yet.  I've got a website that generates a PDF document (and the link to the download of that document) that I'm trying to interact with and Selenium keeps griping that it cannot find the element by the ID, CSS, or xPath locators.

Here is the code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(
    ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("lnkMeetingAgenda_9829")));
Assert.That(element.Displayed);
element.Click();
driver.Close();
```

I don't believe the element is located in a different frame as I don't see it when I inspect the website.  Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:  I believe I know the answer now in looking more at the HTML.  The ID isn't unique as there are 2 instances of it, but that doesn't explain why xPath or CSS aren't working.  Any additional help is appreciated.

```
<a href="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Meetings/ViewMeeting?id=9829&amp;doctype=1"
            title="View Agenda for Audio/Video Media Meeting with Captions Hyland County Council on 5/22/2018 4:55:42 PM" id="lnkMeetingAgenda_9829">Agenda</a>
        <a href="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Documents/Downloadfile/Audio_Video_Media_Meeting_with_Captions_9829_Agenda_5_22_2018_4_55_42_PM.pdf?documentType=1&amp;meetingId=9829" id="lnkMeetingAgendaDoc_9829" target="_blank"
            title="Download Agenda for Audio/Video Media Meeting with Captions Hyland County Council on 5/22/2018 4:55:42 PM">
            <img src="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Images/PDF_16x16.png" />
        </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <a href="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Meetings/ViewMeeting?id=9829&amp;doctype=1"
                id="lnkViewMedia_9829" title="View Media for Audio/Video Media Meeting with Captions Hyland County Council on 5/22/2018 4:55:42 PM">View Media</a>

                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>

                    <td class="hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">

                                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Meetings/ViewMeeting?id=9829&amp;doctype=1"
            title="View Agenda for Audio/Video Media Meeting with Captions Hyland County Council on 5/22/2018 4:55:42 PM" id="lnkMeetingAgenda_9829">Agenda</a>
        <a href="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Documents/Downloadfile/Audio_Video_Media_Meeting_with_Captions_9829_Agenda_5_22_2018_4_55_42_PM.pdf?documentType=1&amp;meetingId=9829" id="lnkMeetingAgendaDoc_9829" target="_blank"
            title="Download Agenda for Audio/Video Media Meeting with Captions Hyland County Council on 5/22/2018 4:55:42 PM">
            <img src="/OnBaseAgendaOnline/Images/PDF_16x16.png" />
```

Comment: Show the clickable element please

Comment: Post a link to the page.

Comment: Is this Id `lnkMeetingAgenda_9829` valid?

Comment: Please Share the block of HTML code,

Answer (score 0):

It happened to be that the ID I was looking for was nested under a "hidden" element so I used the IJavaScriptExecutor to "click" the element.  Below is the code I used to do that.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Thanks everyone for providing help!